# How do I config pycharm to create virtual envrioment in current project by using pipenv?

Tags: python, pycharm, pipenv

In my windows10 system,I try to use pipenv to manage my virtual enviroments.I already config system enviroment variable `WORKON_HOME = PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT`.
[image]
I can create a project virtual enviroment in powershell by using `pipenv install`,it works fine,I can use `pipenv shell` activate virtual enviroment.And in virtual enviroment,I use `where python` to locate python interpreter, it point to `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT\<my project>-4eds3w7u\Scripts\python.exe`.

But when I use pycharm to create python project,It shows`PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT\<my project>-D3tZcIuT\bin\python not found`.
[image]
[image]
This error stop pycharm to create complete project,here is when I use pycharm to create Flask project,the default files,shows it didn't create `app.py`and `templates` file or folder.

[image]

How do I config pycharm to create virtual envrioment in current project by using pipenv?

Answer (score 0):

Open any directory with your source files that contains the Pipenv file then select File Open from the main menu and choose the directory. If PyCharm cannot autodetect the pipenv executable, specify a path to it. Click OK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).